# What Is the Difference Between asetpts and atempo in FFmpeg Audio Filters?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have been using FFmpeg to slow down or speed up video files (with audio). It seems that to speed up a video, `setpts=0.5*PTS` should be used. However, when speeding up an audio, `asetpts=0.5*PTS` and `atempo=2.0` are both available. What is the difference between these two options? Which is the better option?

Answer (score 3):

Like `setpts`, `asetpts` drops or duplicates audio frame to the specified frame rate while `atempo` changes the speed of audio.

Comparing `asetpts=PTS/2` and `atempo=2.0`, some information is lost when you use in `asetpts`. Try it and you can hear the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use `setpts=0.5*pts` as part of your filter, you'll notice that this only applies to the video stream causing the output to become desynchronized. That's why the `atempo=2.0` option is available and intended to be used in conjunction with `setpts`.

More information can be found [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video)

Comment: But he is saying `asetpts`, not `setpts`, `asetpts` begin with `a`, which means audio, `setpts` is for video,  `asetpts` and `atempo` seems has the similar behavior, both of it can speed up audio, but they must be have some difference, and I don't know their difference too.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ffmpeg official wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video), we can see that `atempo` is recommended.

In my own test case, the asetpts can't work. (I used `ffprobe` to check the `pkt_pts`, it doesn't change. Also, I played it and it doesn't change too)